# Name rotated auditd logs with date

Tags: auditd, log-rotation

Can auditd use a date instead of an integer to name its rotated audit logs? Right now I have

```
audit.log
audit.log.1
audit.log.2
...
```

When `audit.log` fills up all of the files are rotated one number higher. I have a script that backs up the audit logs, and `tar` gets confused when it sees all the files move underneath it. I'd like to name the files by date so that they don't all get moved when `audit.log` fills up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

auditd can't do this. Its built in log rotation works by *size*, not by date.

You should be able to turn off auditd's built in log rotation, and then configure logrotate to rotate its logs. It *does* name files by date. In `/etc/audit/auditd.conf`:

```
num_logs = 0
```

In `/etc/logrotate.d/auditd` (tune as you wish):

```
/var/log/audit/audit.log {
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    rotate 2
    compress
    delaycompress
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/systemctl kill -s USR1 auditd.service >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```

(The USR1 signal tells auditd to rotate its logs. Since it is configured not to rotate its logs itself, this just causes it to open a new log, which occurs just after logrotate has rotated the log.)